# PCB design for 13A/12V Circuit

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

I am new to PCB design and am building a PCB circuit powered by a 2200mAH, 25C , 3S lipo battery, the maximum current that will be drawn from this would be 13 Amps.

I usually use the trace calculator to figure out the thickness of the trace. However, this is the first time i am working with current greater than 2 Amps. So, i just want to make sure i dont have to do something special, when designing a 2 layer pcb that has 13 amps of current running through its veins.

Comment: Have a good fuse.

Comment: What is your pcb copper weight? What is your max acceptable temperature rise?

Comment: @laptop2d i usually have the copper weight set at 2 oz. Only because thats the default value that is already set. 

And i dont have any specific temperature requirements.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter how big your trace is. Temperature rise is one of the main parameters in the trace sizing equations.

Comment: Make sure the solder pad (and lead with solder) contact a large area so heat is not concentrated at the through-hole.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik is there a way to calculate this area based on the current?

Comment: If heat is a problem then voltage drop will be a bigger problem with loss of torque and power.  COnsider busbars instead.

Comment: Look at competing products.  Increase size by 25% for a good quality design that may have some tricks you do not understand. Or increase size by 100% (double up) from a generic design that will burn out in a few months.  Keep high current traces as short as possible and connect decent wires as close to power components as possible as they will carry more than most PCB traces and have more free air cooling available.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the following information:  What is the duty cycle (% on time, versus off time, if there is a cyclic operation), how long is the power trace expected to be from the battery input terminal to the load (motors?), what is the load type (motor, heater coil, etc), and what is acceptable voltage drop (is 0.2 volt okay? or 0.5 volt? etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The resistance of copper traces account for more power loss and heat generation when they carry high current.

Larger cross-sectional area have lower resistance, which reduces the amount of power lost to heat. As you mentioned you know how thick your trace should be but there are other factors also which should be considered while designing high power PCB.

The main hazard is heat, This must always be considered when the housing is made, and external vents/fans should be used.

To reduce the amount of heat produced on the board itself, it is best to choose components with low resistance.

the next main hazard is short circuit As you are designing board with power traces, when shorted it will be able to consume considerable amount of power. The easiest way to deal with this problem is to use FUSE.the fuses should be always be rated for less current than wire can handle

Answer (score 0):

[You might find this useful. It's an online trace width calculator](https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html) which also shows temperature rises you can expect. Probably not the only one, but representative of what is available free.

Answer (score -2):

You can design a 2 layer PCB. But you just used to 2OZ(70um) copper for TOP & Bottom.

if you need design PCB for 12A/12V circuit, you need router 5MM(200mil) copper width to it.

Comment: Your comment makes a lot of statements (which are debatable), and has not enough explanation. it also has your personal email, which is not normal to include in answers on this platform (electrical engineering stack exchange). Questions and clarifications are meant to be public, in this comments section, and you can edit your answer publicly, to help others in future.